# Помогите записать цикл из формы в БД

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Нужно записать INSERT столько раз, сколько элементов в цикле вот в такую таблицу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть  у новой записи меняются ATTRIBUTE_ID и ATTRIBUTE_NAME, а все остальное статично

```
<form method="post" action="/objects/complete">
<h3>Добавить</h3>
<table>

  
          
                <input hidden value=@ViewBag.type name="category_id">
    <tr><td><b><label>Название</label></b></td><td><input type="text" name="name" required></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b><label>Описание</label></b></td><td><input type="text" name="about" required></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b><label>Цена</label></b></td><td><input type="text" name="price" required></td></tr>
   

    @foreach (var list in ViewBag.listSvoist)
    {



        <tr><td>
                <input hidden name="@list.Id" value="@list.Id">
                <b><label>@list.Name</label></b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input required name="attribute_name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    }

</table>
  
<button type="submit" value="">Добавить</button>
</form>
```